# Selenium Server (RC) Output Results in Different Format from HTML i.e. Junit XML

Tags: xml, selenium, junit, rc

I have managed to automate my Selenium Suite (run using Selenium Server, formally RC) so that it runs each night and the resulting report is in HTML format.

The command I am running is:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "https://my_webiste_url" "C:\Selenium\Scripts\Selenium-Suite.htm" "C:\Selenium\Results\Result.htm"
```

Is it possible to output the results (currently in HTML) in a more standard format for reporting such as Junit XML?

This would be ideal for me as I can then get Team City (CI Server) to suck in the results and report any errors in our nightly build.

As it stands, we have to manually check our results.html each morning to see if our test are still ok.

Cheers for any help.

Duncan